# Complemented subspaces in a dual Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $Y$ be a complemented subspace in a dual Banach space $X$. *Is it true  that $Y$ is itself isomorphic to a dual?*

This is the case of a  $w^*$-closed subspace $Y$, but a complemented subspace of $X^*$ need not be $w^*$-closed (for instance $Z^*\subset Z^{***}$  is complemented but never  $w^*$-closed unless $Z$ is reflexive). I think it is not true, but is there a simple counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L^1$ is complemented in the measure space $M([0,1])$, $L^1$ is not a dual space.